# range selector in month and year picker in jquery ui

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have two textbox which month and year picker using jquery-UI.it works fine for both the textboxes. Now i want that if user select some month in from(textbox) then mindate(month) for the to(textbox) should be the month selected by user in From textbox.How could i achieve this.
Here is my code for displaying month and year picker.

```
            $("#<%=frm_txtdatefrm.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'M yy'
        }).focus(function () {
            var thisCalendar = $(this);
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
            $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function () {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            });
        });

        $("#<%=frm_txtdateto.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'M yy'
        }).focus(function () {
            var thisCalendar = $(this);
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
            $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function () {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of selecting a date range on the [jQuery UI website](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range).

Add a function for the [onClose event](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) and set a value for the [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) option.

Here is the code from the example:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```